# Polymer content insertion points?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I am trying to build a grid element, but am having some issues with a content insertion points. Here's my element with content insertion points:

```
<template>
<content select="[data-guerilla-grid-service]"></content>
<table id="guerillaGrid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{columns}}" as="column">
        <th style$="{{getColumnStyle(column)}}" data-sort-field$="{{column.sortField}}" on-click="sortClick"><span>{{column.header}}</span></th>
      </template>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <content select="[data-guerilla-grid-items]"></content>
</table>
```

And here's where I'm using it:

```
<template>
<guerilla-grid id="feedbackGrid">
  <muted-feedback-service id="service" items="{{items}}" data-guerilla-grid-service on-load-finished="serviceLoadFinished" sort-field="Version"></muted-feedback-service>

  <tbody data-guerilla-grid-items>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
      <tr>
        <td>{{item.formattedTimestamp}}</td>
        <td>{{item.hash}}</td>
        <td>{{item.version}}</td>
        <td>{{item.serialNumber}}</td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </tbody>
</guerilla-grid>
```

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

Content selector does not appear to work with  tag.  Switched to a doing a table with divs using css display attribute table options.